# Reading date in excel file through ExcelJS give wrong date

Tags: node.js, date, datetime, timezone, exceljs

I am working at EST timezone. When I reading a date in Excel file with the help of [ExcelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs). The date in Excel is `3/31/2021`. But the same date is retrieving as `Tue Mar 30 2021 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`. So it is considering the given date as UTC and converting it to my current timezone. I dont want to convert it to UTC and then to my current timezone. I want to read the direct date which is present in the EXCEL file.

I see dateUTC: false somewhere in the document. This is used at Writing the file. But how to do it when I am reading the excel file. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

First I converted the GMT date to milliseconds using `Date.parse()` and added the time difference between GMT and the current time zone (in my case Asia / Tashkent +5) to the resulting value, then converted it back to a regular date using new Date(milliseconds)

```
let m = Date.parse(gmtDate); //GMT date in milliseconds

let mTZ = m + 18000000; //Asia/Tashkent +5 time zone. 18.000.000 = 5 hours in milliseconds.

let currentDate = new Date(mTZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently and had to do the same thing:

1. Read from excel as UTC
2. then convert into the timezone I wanted for data

I know from your question you don't want to do this, so perhaps this plan is something to fall back on.

My code was something like this:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')
let utc = moment.utc(excelCellStr, 'M/D/YY hh:mm A')
let t = moment().tz('America/New_York')
t.year(utc.year())
t.month(utc.month())
t.date(utc.date())
t.hour(utc.hour())
t.minute(utc.minute())
t.second(utc.second())
excelCellStr = t.format()
```

I am not sure if there is a setting to avoid this or not. We are using [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) as well.

Comment: Hi clay, i used timezone as 'America/New_York', but excelCellStr is retunring data like -0NaN--NaN--NaNT-NaN:-NaN:-NaN+00:00. Could you please suggest what I am missing here. My code is exactly similar to above one.

Comment: I made one edit to the code that I forgot about. `moment` is not plain moment, it is `moment-timezone`.  Otherwise make sure the format of your excel string is the format expected (in the example, format was 'M/D/YY hh:mm A')

Comment: Actually I am also using `moment-timezone`only but still same error.

Comment: maybe it did not parse correctly? What is the string value of the cell before the moment stuff? does `t.isValid()` return true? Sorry I can't help more, maybe update your question with some code or values you're seeing.